# Communication Gazebo Ros GPS

Tags: ros, gazebo, gps, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I need help to create a topic for the communication between a gazebo plugin and a ros node. The plugin receives the GPS measures and it should publish on a ros topic the data. The problem is that I have not understood how to make the communication between the plugin and the ros topic. Have you got any idea? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267156/communication-gazebo-ros-gps/) by [tonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/30285/tonio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your plugin needs a node handle to publish ROS messages. Here is an example of a [GPS plugin](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_gazebo/blob/indigo-devel/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_gps.cpp) for Gazebo.

Especially look at the following lines:

```
152. node_handle_ = new ros::NodeHandle(namespace_);
153. fix_publisher_ = node_handle_->advertise<sensor_msgs::NavSatFix>(fix_topic_, 10);
```

```
236. fix_publisher_.publish(fix_);
```

---

Originally posted by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) with karma: 775 on 2017-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1